# Extra Classpath In Eclipse Like DrJave

Tags: java, eclipse, drjava, eclipse-classpath

In my elementary/high school programming classes, we're moving from DrJava to Eclipse as primary IDE. I use SimpleTurtle to teach concepts. In DrJava, I just go to Preferences and add Extra Classpath. Boom, DONE!  Students can then seamlessly use the World and Turtle (EX World w = new World();) classes without understanding what they are doing which is great for first time programmers and opens the door for future lessons on methods, classes, and constructors without overwhelming them in the beginning.

Here's the question..how do I configure Eclipse to work like DrJava in that a student can start a new project and have access to the World and Turtle classes without taking any additional steps? I currently just point DrJava to the TurtleGraphics folder in DrJava -> Preferences which is the preferred method but using a .jar file would be fine as well.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Project folder in Project explorer menu, now in the menu bar click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path, there you will get options to add jars, add external jars and add other project sources.